# MGV Dataminer for IBM/Toshiba 4690 ODBC Driver

Tags: sql, odbc, driver, pos

I have a few sites that use MGV Dataminer that essentially is a keyed/direct file to sql engine. It allows you to query the 4690 GSA/SA/ACE keyed files as if it were an SQL server via ODBC. I am migrating a few of our servers, and I am in search of the windows ODBC driver/client for this product. The company that wrote Dataminer is no longer. Does anyone know where I could find the windows/client side driver for this or know of a compatible one?

Answer (score 0):

Try TRUNO Retail Solutions for the 32-bit version of MGV Dataminer, you may be able to purchase a copy from them.

I have both of the Dataminer connections (ODBC and TCP/IP) working on Windows 10 32-bit using the odbcad32.exe version 3.525.1132.0 that I got from windows XP.

The 4690 tables are linked in Access, and the data is flowing in both directions; so it's totally do-able as long as you stay in a 32-bit environment.